# GNSS Dead Reckoning -- Sensor Fusion Filter not necessary?

Tags: imu, sensor-fusion, filter, dead-reckoning, gnss

My question might be a bit off-topic but I don't know where else to ask.

When I do have a `GNSS Module` with integrated `IMU` and `Dead Reckoning`, for example, the [Ublox ZED - F9K](https://www.u-blox.com/en/product/zed-f9k-module#tab-documentation-resources).

Does it still make sense to use a `Filter` for fusing GNSS and IMU / Odometry data or is that not necessary as the Module is handling that for me?

Or will the Dead Reckoning just enhance the precision after applying a Filter even more?

Comment: Ah, let me google and see if I can answer you question. I first skimmed the following ***ZED-F9K Product Summary***: https://www.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/ZED-F9K_ProductSummary_%28UBX-19047326%29.pdf

Comment: I also read the module product sheet from Sparkun and made a features summary: "GPS-RTK2 Board (ZED-F9P) Product Sheet - SparkFun": 
https://www.mouser.hk/new/sparkfun/sparkfun-gps-rtk2-board/
(1) ***TTFF = 25s (cold), 2s (hot)***; 
(2) Horizontal accuracy = 2.5m (without RTK), ***10cm (with RTK)***;
(3) Nag rate = 25Hz max

Comment: I then browse the SparkFun GNSS 23 Products Catalog:
https://www.sparkfun.com/categories/tags/gnss, and the 
***GPS-RTK ZED-F9R Dead Reckoning Breakout*** - SparkFun ***US$300***
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/16344.

Comment: I also skimmed SparkFun's "GPS-***RTK Dead Reckoning ZED-F9R Hookup Guide***":
https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/sparkfun-gps-rtk-dead-reckoning-zed-f9r-hookup-guide.

Comment: I then read SparkFun's Hookup Guide: "***GPS-RTK Dead Reckoning ZED-F9R Hookup Guide (Python and Arduino)***":
https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/sparkfun-gps-rtk-dead-reckoning-zed-f9r-hookup-guide.

Comment: SparkFun's tutorials are always very newbie friendly. If it has a guide for Arduino, then it should be of middle difficulty level. If it has a tutorial for python, then I think it should be as easy for Rpi python programmers. I once used Rpi python to access data from uBlox uCenter and found everything straightforward. (1) GPS taking long time to fix out in the open - EE SE, 2020sep03, Viewed 2k times
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/519711/gps-taking-long-time-to-fix-out-in-the-open/519716#519716. /to continue, ...

Comment: (2) Rpi Neo-6M/7M/8M GPS Module Setup/Fix/Update Problems - Rpi SE 2020jun18
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/113544/rpi-neo-6m-neo-8m-gps-module-setup-fix-update-problems/113601#113601.

Answer (score 1):

***Question***

*Is it necessary to use any filter to fuse Ublox ZED-F9K's GNSS and IMU/Odometry
data?*

---

[image: zed-9fr]

---

***Answer***

***My answer is NO***, *for the following reasons:*

(1)  GNSS and IMU are independently developed modules with matured software. It is unlikely for the vendor to "fuse" them at the hardware level.  A more efficient method is to let the MCU/SBC to talk to either or both guys using I2C,  UART, or SPI.

(2) uBlox uCenter uses very simple, text based NMEA0183 protocol, and update rate is of the order of 25Hz, so the user can easily pass the slow GNSS data to IMU for processing.

---

***Discussion, Conclusion, and Recommendation***

I think it is not a good idea to use the expensive US$300 ZED-F9K module to do any feasibility studies.  I would suggest to use two separate modules (1) UART NEO-8M, (2) Any I2C IMU and use Rpi python to do any system integration test.

---

***References***

(1) [SparkFun GNSS Products Catalog](https://www.sparkfun.com/categories/tags/gnss)

(2) [GPS-RTK ZED-F9R Dead Reckoning Breakout - SparkFun US$300](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/16344)

(3) [SparkFun GPS-RTK Dead Reckoning ZED-F9R Hookup Guide (Python)](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/sparkfun-gps-rtk-dead-reckoning-zed-f9r-hookup-guide)

(4) [GPS Fixing Time Problem Q&A - tlfong01, EE SE, 2020sep03](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/519711/gps-taking-long-time-to-fix-out-in-the-open/519716#519716)

(5) [Neo-6M/7M/8M GPS Module Setup/Fix/Update Problem Q&A - tlfong01 Rpi SE 2020jun18](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/113544/rpi-neo-6m-neo-8m-gps-module-setup-fix-update-problems/113601#113601)

---